# Inside closure function statement not executing

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a small question about closure functions. I have the closure function below:

```js
var add = (function() {
  var counter = 0;
  console.log('Executed');
  return function() {
    return counter += 1;
  };
})();

add();
```

It is a self invoking function so first time every statement executes, but when i call `add()` method inside of the closure statements not executing except the `return` statement.

Comment: what you are trying to do ? its behaviour is correct according to closure

Comment: Need more info indeed. As written, the code looks ok. On startup, you get the console.log. And then each time you call add, it returns the next value of counter (1,2,3,...) If you mean the console.log should be executed every time add is called, just move it into the function your returned.

Answer (score 0):

Have a glance at the logs after running the snippet.

```js
console.log('Before first execution.');
var add = (function() {
  console.log('Inside First time execution');
  var counter = 0;
  console.log('Executed');
  console.log('Returning a Funciton.');
  // Inner Function.
  return function() {
    console.log('Inner function called.')
    return counter += 1;
  }
})();
console.log('End of first execution');
console.log('Start of second execution');
add();
console.log('End of second execution');
```

`add()` is a self-invoking function which gets immediately. Now while invoking there is a a function being returned. Now trick is this newly returned function(lets say `inner` function) is assigned back to the variable `add`. So now this `add` turns to be pointing/ refering to this `inner` function.

In the second execution, thus when you are invoking `add()`, it had been pointing to the inner function which gets invoked.